# How to show help popups on controls in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I'm using following code to show some popup.

```
if(isIdDuplicated) {
    showTooltip(stage, textField_id, "This id have already been used!");
}

public static void showTooltip(Stage owner, Control control, String tooltipText) {
    Point2D p = control.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);

    final Tooltip customTooltip = new Tooltip();
    customTooltip.setText(tooltipText);

    control.setTooltip(customTooltip);

    customTooltip.show(owner, p.getX()
        + control.getScene().getX() + control.getScene().getWindow().getX(), p.getY()
        + control.getScene().getY() + 

    control.getScene().getWindow().getY());
}
```

Here is the problem I had to face: When moving the window, above help popups(actually tool tips) are not moving with the textField_id. Can anybody tell me the best way to do this like functionality without using tool tips? Is there any third party library with help popup like controls in JavaFX?

Here is an example for well known help popup: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

like something like this?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("My story");
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setStyle("-fx-background-image : url(\"http://thechronicle.com.gh/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Juliet-Ibrahim.jpg\")");
    Button b = new Button("GET TO KNOW HER");
    b.setStyle("-fx-background-color : white;");
    b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent paramT) {
            Popup p = new Popup();
            VBox hbox = new VBox(0); //it was hbox at first
            hbox.setFillWidth(true);
            hbox.setPrefWidth(400);
            hbox.setMinHeight(400);
            hbox.setPadding(new Insets(4));
            hbox.setEffect(new DropShadow());
            hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white; -fx-background-radius: 5;");

            Label l = new Label("You see i went to school with this woman, private school, but i was little like at age 7, and she was like 14"
                    + "\n  see i could barely get an erection, lol, and you see we were very noisy kids, hence they seniors always came to shut us up."
                    + " see i was a very very bad 7 year old, and you know how these teen chicks they love bad kids, lol. but i was too young.");
            l.setWrapText(true);
            l.setPrefWidth(400);
            l.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");
            HBox.setHgrow(l, Priority.SOMETIMES);

            Label l1 = new Label("Look at her y'all, she married though, but you know crazy me, i had all these and i i fell in love with ruby and some chick name java"
                    + ", i dont know what i was thinking,"
                    + " i dont know who cursed me, lol, shit, here name is Juiliet Ibrahim. lol, thats my sister,"
                    + " you see its not very hard to replicate, i have lights out, runing on a 30 mins laptop, this demo, i will pimp it tomorrow,"
                    + " aka - show you more pics of my sister lol.");
            l1.setWrapText(true);
            l1.setPrefWidth(400);
            l1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white; -fx-text-fill: black;");
            HBox.setHgrow(l1, Priority.SOMETIMES);

            Label l2 = new Label("THIS IS A POP UP MENU");
            l2.setWrapText(true);
            l2.setPrefWidth(400);
            l2.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blueviolet; -fx-text-fill: white;");
            l2.setFont(Font.font(Font.getFontNames().get(18), FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, 22));
            HBox.setHgrow(l1, Priority.SOMETIMES);

            hbox.getChildren().addAll(l,
                    new HBox(new ImageView(new Image("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/82/57/c1/8257c1c3e05d3e5c0d8a945e9d1b8a11.jpg",133,0,true,true,true)),
                    new ImageView(new Image("https://www.bellanaija.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Juliet-Ibrahim-2-600x867.jpg",133,0,true,true,true)),
                    new ImageView(new Image("http://www.gistus.com/gs-c/uploads/2015/10/juliet8.jpg",133,0,true,true,true))),
                    l1,l2);
            p.getContent().add(hbox);
            p.setAnchorX(b.getLayoutX() + b.getTranslateX() + stage.getX()+ b.prefWidth(-1) + 5);//just for demo
            p.setAnchorY(b.getLayoutY() + b.getTranslateY() + stage.getY()+ b.prefHeight(-1));//just for demo
            //for demostration sake
            Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>() {

                @Override
                public Double call() throws Exception {
                    return 0.0;
                }
            }, stage.xProperty(),stage.yProperty());
            new DoubleBinding() {
                {
                    super.bind(stage.xProperty());
                    super.bind(stage.yProperty());
                }
                @Override
                protected double computeValue() {
                    return stage.xProperty().add(stage.yProperty()).get();//dont try this at work :)
                }
            }.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> paramObservableValue, Number paramT1,
                        Number paramT2) {
                    p.setAnchorX(b.getLayoutX() + b.getTranslateX() + stage.getX()+ b.prefWidth(-1) + 5);//just for demo
                    p.setAnchorY(b.getLayoutY() + b.getTranslateY() + stage.getY()+ b.prefHeight(-1));//just for demo

                }
            });
            p.setAutoFix(true);
            p.show(stage);

        }
    });
    bp.setBottom(b);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(bp,600,500));
    stage.show();
}
```

[image]